# Django run function when new instance is created/edited and have the function change a variable in the instance created/edited

Tags: python, django, backend

I have a Django model that has a user inputted field called reserve_time. When a user enters and creates (or edits) a instance of the class I want a function to run and check if the time inputted is during dinner or lunch. I have been trying to use post_save to do this but it hasn't been working, the print statement would say if it was dinner or not but the instance of the class would not be changed at all. Also the current way I'm doing it `Reservation.objects.last()` only works if right if I create a new instance, not if I edit an old one.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
import operator
from django.utils.timezone import now, localtime
from django.db.models.signals import post_save


# Create your models here.

class Reservation(models.Model):
    shift = ''
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    member_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="")
    guest_num = models.IntegerField()
    reserve_time = models.TimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} at {self.reserve_time.strftime('%I:%M %p')} ({self.shift}) {self.date_created.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')}"



def model_created_or_updated(sender, **kwargs):
    the_instance = kwargs['instance']
    reservation = Reservation.objects.last()

    if reservation.reserve_time < datetime.time(17, 10, 0):
        reservation.shift = 'lunch'
        print('lunch')
    else:
        reservation.shift = 'dinner'
        print('dinner')

    print('model created/updated')

post_save.connect(model_created_or_updated, sender=Reservation)
```

Is there a substitute for Reservation.objects.last() that just calls the specific instance I am changing or adding? and how come my changing the variable shift in the if/else statement doesn't actually change it? My end goal is for this to work automatically anytime a new instance is created/edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what for do you use     `reservation = Reservation.objects.last()`?
you have an `instance` that sends signal to you

```
the_instance = kwargs['instance']
if the_instance.reserve_time < datetime.time(17, 10, 0):
    the_instance.shift = 'lunch'
    print('lunch')
else:
    the_instance.shift = 'dinner'
    print('dinner')

print('model created/updated')
```

you can do it other way - override `save` method of your model

```
class Reservation(models.Model):
...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.reserve_time < datetime.time(17, 10, 0):
            self.shift = 'lunch'
            print('lunch')
        else:
            self.shift = 'dinner'
            print('dinner')
        print('model created/updated')
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Oops, I completely missed that. Thank you! Do you know why the shift variable isn't changing?

Comment: you don't store it to database, it changes for a life period of a single object, if you want to save it to database, then declare it as `shift=models.CharField(max_length=40)`, but then you need to check in your signal, if you don't want to have infinite loop

Comment: added another variant for you, so you can redeclare `shift` as `CharField` and don't be afraid of infinite loop in signal(when you change model in after post signal and save it again)

Comment: Where would I put the save method? Inside of the Model? I put it in the model, just needed to add self in ```def save(self, *args, **kwargs):``` Thank you!

Comment: modified answer

Comment: you are right, forgot to put `self` as first argument